# nodejs - How to have request inside then?

Tags: node.js

I need to generate a `key` first then use the `key` to run `request` Below code is just an example

```
 const getKey = () => {
        return new Promises(resolve, reject) => {
            const value =  somecode here;
             resolve (value);
        }
    }

getKey().then(val => {
    request({method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.google.com', key: val}, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error){
                console.log(body)
            }

        }); 
    }
});
```

How can I chain them together using `Promises`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `request-promise` library instead and then just return the inner promise from inside of the `.then()` handler.

You pretty much never want to mix plain async callbacks with promises.  When presented with that challenge, the first thing to do is to "promisify" the async callback to use a promise so you can then chain promises.  In this case, the `request-promise` library is already a promisified version of the `request` library.  Here's how you would do that.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const getKey = () => {
        return new Promises(resolve, reject) => {
            const value =  somecode here;
             resolve (value);
        }
    }

getKey().then(val => {
    return rp({method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.google.com', key: val});
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This will chain the inner promise to the outer one so that the final result of the promise chain is the result from the inner promise.

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.